# Jenkins NodeLabelParameter Plugin not displaying

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed the NodeLabelParameter Plugin to allow me to set a node to use for a build, but when selecting Node or Label parameter types the parameter box isn't appended to the list of parameters. I can see the render request in network tab with the expected html. No errors in console.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Plugin, removed other Plugins to see if there was any conflicts but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone ever had this issue before and might be able to advise?

I am running Jenkins 1.264.3 and NodeLabelParameter (1.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

After some serious debugging, I found the last script to run before Jenkins getting the render file was Adguard. This seemed to have been the issue, disabled Adguard and next click of adding the parameter it appeared.